# Unable to use correctly composer autoload in plugin file

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, composer

I've installed google php client library because I need to integrate some google services inside my wordpress dashboard. I've some classes that I will need to load inside my main plugin file, I've added the `autoload` field to the composer.json file and run the `composer dump-autoload` command but now all my classes stopped working and are not loaded

```json
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "2.15.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Drive",
            "Calendar",
            "Forms"
        ]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["inc"]
    }
}
```

is there something wrong with the composer json file? I'm calling the `autoload.php` file inside my main plugin file.

```php
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ){
 wp_die();
}

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class MyPlugin {
  ...
}

new MyPlugin();
```

Any help please?